# styling XML (not HTML) with javascript & css after rendering in browser

Tags: javascript, css, xml, safari, webkit

I'm using a webkit browser (safari), so this question is specific to webkit.

I have safari rendering an XML document (it's not HTML). In order to style certain sections of the document, I've attached a stylesheet (see below) to the document.  In the case below, the text within the first "thing" element is displayed in magenta.

This works reasonably well.  But I would also like to ***dynamically modify the style*** of various elements (I assume by using javascript) ***after the document has been rendered***.

I can use javascript to capture the first "thing" element using **document.getElementsByName("a").item(0);** but I'm not sure how to set the style (or if this is possible at all).  this does not work => **document.getElementsByName("a").item(0).style.display = "none";**

Any thoughts on how to change the style of an xml element in a browser after it's been rendered?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="simple.css" type="text/css"?>
<document xmlns:ab="adfadfafadf">
  <thing name="a">stuff</thing>
  <thing name="b">stuff2</thing>
</document>
```

_

```
//simple.css________________________________
document {margin: 1em; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px;}
thing[name="a"] {color: magenta;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use javascript to capture the first "thing" element using document.getElementsByName("a").item(0)

You shouldn't even be able to do that, and you can't on non-WebKit browsers. `getElementsByName` is a DOM Level 1 HTML method that shouldn't be available on XML documents, which have no notion of `name` attributes having special significance. (This is slightly different to the situation with attributes of schema type `ID`.)

Can you legitimately expect a `style` property to exist on Elements in arbitrary XML documents? The DOM Level 2 Style spec has this to say about the [ElementCSSInlineStyle](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-htmlelementcss) interface:

> The expectation is that an instance of the ElementCSSInlineStyle interface can be obtained by using binding-specific casting methods on an instance of the Element interface when the element supports inline CSS style informations.

I'd argue that an arbitrary XML document's elements do *not* support inline CSS style information, as there is no `style` or other attribute that could be used to introduce CSS, unlike with [X]HTML. Mozilla and Opera agree with WebKit here in not providing it.

However, DOM Level 2 Style's [document.styleSheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-StyleSheet-DocumentStyle) interface should work (in any of those browser bases). For example you can remove the `thing[name="a"]` rule by saying:

```
document.styleSheets[0].deleteRule(1);
```

and add a replacement by saying:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('thing[name="a"] {display: none;}', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look good, but I would try clicking on the links in the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML) to see if WebKit supports the styling you want to do.  If it doesn't, you could dynamically request a stylesheet from the server after you've looked at the data.  That might be the only work around.